# Stop Laravel password validation if username or email is empty

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8, laravel-validation

I have a custom login form that verifies credentials with an API. Everything is working well except that if I leave the username/email field blank and enter a password, the API call is still sent when it should stop before that.

I had a look at the rules `bail`, `required_with` (and other similar) but none of them fits the bill.

Is there a way to have only the validation message:

> The identifier field is required.

Instead of

> The identifier field is required.
>
> Sorry, this is not the password associated with your identifier. Please check and try again.

(stop password validation if username/email is empty?

Controller code, as requested (`ApiMemberPassword` is just a custom rule sending an API request with username and password, which is useless if `identifier` is empty):

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'identifier' => ['required'],
    'password' => ['bail', 'required', new ApiMemberPassword],
]);
```

Comment: Can you show your controller?

Comment: can you show your controller code?

Comment: I did not share code because my request is so simple (Just asking if there's an existing rule for that) and because it would logically look exactly like it would for anyone who used Laravel validation in their life. But hey, thanks for the downvote, so friendly and useful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
 $this->validate($request, [
      'identifier' => 'bail|required',
      'password' => ['required', new ApiMemberPassword],
 ]);
```

Comment: Oh wow!! This works, perfect thanks!  My mistake was adding the "bail" in the password rules instead, I'll change my question so that other users might benefit from this, thanks a lot!

Comment: If you change the question the answer will be useless instead add it as an update.

Comment: It's not actually, I put the code back as it was. Have a look at where I originally put the "bail" and let me know what you think. I'll revert if you're uncomfortable with, along with all these comments to keep it clean

Answer (score 0):

As you have not shared any code whatsoever, here is my suggestion:

- use simple Javascript to validate the fields and enable the "SUBMIT" button only if both fields have values.

As for returning an error only for the email field is concerned, it is not possible using inbuild laravel validation. See the thread [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/4789)

It is simply because, usually for good user experience, all errors regarding a form failure should be displayed at once so that user can correct all of them and submit a correct form the next time. There is no point of correcting a user 5 times on 5 different submits when it could have been done altogether. Makes sense?

However, if you really need this, you just have two fields and you can make your custom validation to first check email and then password, or simply use Laravel inbuild validation twice.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that github issue as well before posting as well as the 31 people upvoting that comment. I agree with you that this kind of conditional validation would need to be corrected on the frontend side, however in this case I don't see why someone would enter a password without a username so this was really just an edge case additionnal safety net. I'll wait a few hours to see if someone else has the backend solution for this to keep all the validation cohesive.

Comment: Oh yeah also, someone can just activate the submit button manually or call the form submit via javascript

Comment: of course, any kind of javascript can be hacked, that is why you have your backend validation in place but still having js validation does restrict 90% of the user who are not hackers :) also you mentioned: `if I leave the username/email field blank and enter a password, the API call is still sent when it should stop before that.` which is not possible in any othe rway but using JS. As for back end validation, as I mentioned, use inbuild validation in chain, once for email and then for password and you should be good to go.